# How to mark a empty cell in a row and mark that row as 0 orelse 1?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Hi I have a excel sheet of 7396 rows and 27 columns. I have some empty cells and I want to mark all empty cell row with 0 and non empty cell rows with 1 Please help how to do that.

Comment: Do you have any code for us to look at?  I would think a if else statement setup in a loop would be sufficient for what you need.

Comment: Sorry meverheart I have know clue how to write code in excel if you know please let me know how can we write code to manipulate the cell values in excel. It would also be great if you please let me know in what language do you code to perform different kind of function in excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

You could easily have found this answer on google...

Click Home > Find & Select > Go To Special…to open the Go To Special dialog box. Then choose Blanks option from Select section.

Then click OK. All of the blank cells will be selected. Then don’t do anything just input the number or text you want into the active cell.

And then press Ctrl + Enter, and all of the blank cells have been filled with the text “null”.

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/772-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-0-or-specific-value.html

Comment: Thank you very much Aiden for giving this valuable information